# TSQL Configurable database name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make my database names configurable to be able to run something like this:

```
declare @x nvarchar(MAX)
declare @y nvarchar(MAX)

set @x = 'database1'
set @y = 'database2'

select * from @x.table1 INNER JOIN @y.table2 ON ....
```

Is there a way how to achieve it on SQL server 2016?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Dynamic SQL*: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: An alternative option is to create views or synonyms over the tables you're looking at, so your statements can point to thost views, then those views point to the underlying tables, giving you some abstraction.  By changing the table used in the view's definition, the query pulls data back from that other table.  That's no good if you're frequently switching tables / have stuff running in parallel, but if this is to work around some issue where you're using different linked servers in test & production & want to abstract away the server/db details, it's a pragmatic approach,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is with SQLCMD variables:

```
:SETVAR x "database1"
:SETVAR y "database2"

SELECT * FROM $(x).dbo.table1 INNER JOIN $(y).dbo.table2 ON ....
```

To run SQLCMD scripts in SSMS, turn on SQLCMD Mode from the Query menu.

If you run the script from the command line using the `SQLCMD` utility, you could omit the `SETVAR` commands and pass the values as command-line arguments.

Comment: Terrific, this is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL.
Your only option is to use dynamic sql for this. (BTW, your code sample suggests you are talking about tables, not databases)

```
declare @x sysname, @sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @x = 'table1', 
       @y = 'table2'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM '+ @x +' INNER JOIN '+ @y +' ON ....'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

However, since this is dynamic SQL, you are opening a door for SQL Injection attacks. 
There are two more things to do to protect yourself:

1. Use `quotename`
2. make sure you actually have these tables in your database

So a better code would be something like this:

```
declare @x sysname, @sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @x = 'table1', 
       @y = 'table2'

IF 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM InformationSchema.Tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME IN(@x, @y)
) = 2 
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM quotename('+ @x +') INNER JOIN quotename('+ @y +') ON ....'

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Comment: You are right, it looks like table, but I really need databases - I changed the example.
Is there a way to avoid dynamicSQL?

Comment: No. Database identifiers are still identifiers. You can use the same technique with databases, but you'll have to check sys.Servers instead of informantionSchema.Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Uses SYNONYMs

```
create SYNONYM YourTableReference FOR YourDatabaseName.dbo.YourTable;

create SYNONYM YourTableRefernce2 FOR YourDatabaseNameNumber2.dbo.YourTable;

select * from YourTableReference r
inner join YourTableRefernce2 r2 on r.Id=r2.Id -- etc . . . .
```